# What exactly does EKS do if CloudFormation is needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

What does AWS' Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) **do exactly** if so much configuration is needed in CloudFormation which is (yet) another AWS service?

I followed the AWS EKS Getting Started in the docs at (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-ug.pdf) where it seems CloudFormation knowledge is **heavily** required to run EKS.
Am I mistaken or something?

So in addition to learning the Kubernetes .yaml manifest definitions, to run k8s on EKS, AWS expects you to learn their CloudFormation .yaml configuration manifests as well (which are all PascalCase as opposed to k8s' camelCase i might add)?

I understand that EKS does some management of latest version of k8s and control plane, and is "secure by default" but other than that?

Why wouldn't I just run k8s on AWS using kops then, and deal with the slightly outdated k8s versions?
Or am I supposed to do EKS + CloudFormation + kops at which point GKE looks like a really tempting alternative?

Update:
At this point I'm really thinking EKS is just a thin wrapper over CloudFormation after searching on EKS in detail and how it is so reliant on CloudFormation manifests.
Likely a business response to the alarming popularity of k8s, GKE in general with no substance to back the service.
Hopefully this helps save the time of anyone evaluating the half-baked service that is EKS.

Comment: CloudFormation is easy. You should try that. Or stay on Azure and keep clicking buttons till you get frustrated and break your monitor.

Comment: however easy CloudFormation is, it is still an unnecessary step for consumers. Essentially there must be something in AWS that translates your CF manifest into a k8s manifest to start your k8s cluster. Note that my question is specific to k8s and not starting any normal cluster (which CF might be good at). Also, I didn't say I was on Azure.

Comment: I would use kops (and I actually do) because they will support more cloud platforms in the future (gce in beta right now) and it is open source.

Comment: agreed and i am on kops now too. just that higher ups wanted to go 'managed service' so I had to evaluate, but I found EKS is not a managed service at all right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run Kubernetes on AWS you have basically 2 options:

- using kops, it will create Master nodes + workers node under the hood, in plain EC2 machines
- EKS + Cloudformation workers stack (you can use also Terraform as an alternative to deploy the workers, or eksctl, that will create both the EKS cluster and the workers. I recommend you to follow [this workshop](https://eksworkshop.com/))

EKS alone provides only the master nodes of a kubernetes cluster, in a highly available setup. You still need to add the worker nodes, where your containers will be created.

I tried both kops and EKS + Workers, and I ended up using EKS, because I found it easier to setup and maintain and more fault-tolerant.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the same difficulties earlier, and none of article could give me requirement in a glance for things that need to be done. Lot of people just recommend using eksctl which in my opinion will create a bloated and hard to manage kind of CloudFormation.

Basically both EKS is just a wrapper of Kubernetes, there's some points of integration between Kubernetes and AWS that still need to be done manually.

I've wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@susanto.bn/aws-kubernetes-eks-part-1-create-using-cloudformation-with-hardened-bastion-4e459250ffd0?source=friends_link&sk=0bba240a36c722e05d1ef06fa0a410d0) that hope could help you understand all the process that need to be inplaces

Answer (score 1):

EKS is the managed control plane for kubernetes , while Cloud-formation is a infrastructure templating service .

Instead of EKS you can run and manage the control plane(master nodes) on top of EC2 machines if you want to optimize for costs.For using EKS you have to pay for the underlying infra(EC2+networking..) and managed service fee(EKS price) .

Cloud-formation provides a nice interface to template and automate your infrastructure.You may use terraform in place of CF